# How do I create a filter for copying binary files in Rake Pipeline (rakep)?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-pipeline

I am using Rake Pipeline (aka "rakep") to build an Ember.js application. I find that when it is running on a Windows OS it mangles binary image files when it is copying them.

The [Ruby docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rake-pipeline/0.5.0/frames) indicate that you need to introduce a special filter that looks like this:

```
class ConcatFilter < Rake::Pipeline::Filter
  processes_binary_files
  def generate_output(inputs, output)
    inputs.each do |input|
      output.write input.read
    end
  end
end
```

but I can't see how I introduce this into my build process so that I can specify this filter in my Assetfile.